# UserControl not loading in ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, user-controls

I've create my own UserControl called 'ReevooBadge' and have placed it in my listview by registering my UserControl. However, my UserControl isn't visible in the ListView.  Any sugestions for this problem?

This is my User Control

```
     <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReevooBadge.ascx.cs"   Inherits="KiaEurope2010.Website.controls.Addons.Widgets.ReevooBadge" %>
     <a class="reevoomark <%= this.ClassName %>" href="//mark.reevoo.com/partner/<%= this.CountryCode %>/series:<%= this.SelectionIdentifier %>"><%= this.ReviewsTitle %></a>
```

I need to implement this in my ListView by the following code implementation

```
     <asp:ListView ID="lvItemCarousel" ItemPlaceholderID="carrouselitems"OnItemDataBound="lvItemCarousel_ItemDataBound"
                runat="server">
                <layouttemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="carrouselitems" runat="server" />
                </layouttemplate>
                <itemtemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hlItem">
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imItem" />
                            <div class="modelTitle">
                                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phReevoo" Visible="false">
                                  <rhm:ReevooBadge runat="server" ID="ReevooBadge" /> 
                                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </div>
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                </itemtemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Above I register my custom User Control

```
            <%@ Register Src="~/controls/Addons/Widgets/ReevooBadge.ascx" TagPrefix="rhm" TagName="ReevooBadge" %>
```

And in the Item Data Binding

```
            protected void lvItemCarousel_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
            {
            //...
                phReevoo.Visible = true;
                ReevooBadge.ModelItem = this.Item;
                ReevooBadge.CountryCode = KiaEurope.SitecoreLayer.Reevoo.Settings.GetReevooKey(LanguageCountryCultureHelper.CurrentCountryCode, Sitecore.Context.Language);
            }
```

However, the user control isn't visible in the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're getting your code to compile because I couldn't reference `phReevoo` (the `placeholder` control) directly in the ItemDataBound event.

I needed to use the following:

```
 e.Item.FindControl("phReevoo").Visible = true;
```

The same would apply if you tried to reference `ReevooBadge`.

To make the testing easier I created a web user control and used this as a substitute for your custom user control. After binding to a simple `List<string>`, the control showed without issue.

I would suggest checking if your user control is actually rendering outside of the `ListView`.